# Memory for ASUS 1005 HAB

Tags: memory

What is maximum memory I can put in an ASUS 1005 HAB laptop? It presently has 1 GB, can I go to 2 GB and what is the memory specification to order?
 I want to upgrade to System 7.

Comment: Have you checked their site? http://www.asus.com/

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can upgrade to 2 GB.  However you will have to replace the RAM currently in the laptop with a 2 GB stick since you only have one slot.  Here is the details of what is supported:

[image]